# Getting 'Request processing failed' while doing TestNG PUT request in gradle mockmvc

Tags: unit-testing, testing, gradle, testng, mockmvc

Getting below exception while running PUT request Test case using mockmvc.
The Mockmvc code for unit testing is this:

```
mockMvc.perform(put("/images/"+id)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("X-Client-Type", "STOS")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtTokenResponse.getAccessToken())
                .content(convertObjectToString(imageRequest)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The exception is below for the same testcase:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:919)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
00:41:31.144 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.PatternMappingFilterProxy.doFilter(PatternMappingFilterProxy.java:101)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
00:41:31.145 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at com.ril.api.auth.filter.JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:122)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
00:41:31.146 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
00:41:31.147 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at controller.ImageControllerTests.testImagesPut(ImageControllerTests.java:336)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:41:31.148 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:200)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:180)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
00:41:31.149 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
00:41:31.150 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:141)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:90)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
00:41:31.151 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
00:41:31.152 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         Caused by:
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         java.lang.NullPointerException
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at com.ril.service.cms.controller.ImageController.updateImageDetails(ImageController.java:136)
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at com.ril.service.cms.controller.ImageController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$689e4489.invoke(<generated>)
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
00:41:31.153 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at com.ril.service.cms.controller.ImageController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b7ab9e1d.updateImageDetails(<generated>)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
00:41:31.154 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
00:41:31.155 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
00:41:31.155 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
00:41:31.155 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             ... 119 more
00:41:31.156 [QUIET] [system.out] 
00:41:31.156 [QUIET] [system.out] </event></ijLog>
00:41:31.156 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
00:41:31.156 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle suite > Gradle test FAILED
```

What is needed to corrected here?

What is the root cause for this?

How to avoid this scenario?